# Google Sheets Data Validation Regexmatch

Tags: regex, validation, google-sheets

I would like to create data validation for a cell that contains multiple bits of data, each separated by a comma or semi-colon.  The first bit of info would be the time (eg 14:30) and the second bit would be a string.  I would like the data validation part to check that the time is a time (I have that formula as a regexmatch) but then after the comma or semi-colon, I would like data validation checking the string against a range or list of strings...can this be done?

EDIT

link here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CGJj_R3eUfxmYUDStNlkIwiyrcbFKfMWH8VXZ7rpwwk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Yes, it can be done. You should present a small set of data representative of your data and explain where your effort succeeds and fails.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have added the spreadsheet with data.  I have the regexmatch formula the correctly tests that a time is true (i vaguely know how this works, but it's a buit over my head).  As for the next stage of having the formula test for validation within a range or list, I have no idea and can't find much info how to go about implementing it.  i also would like to test a string against another list after another comma or semi-colon if that is possible.